# Geometry generator QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, geometry-generator

In QGIS 3.22.4, I've a WFS layer with measurements of soil-depths (`LayerFrom` & `LayerTo`) in the attribute table. With the symbology-geometry generator, I've created **scalable** circles (geometry type = polygon, unit = pixels) in the center of each layer, next to the coordinates of the measurements. The expression looks like this:

`make_circle(make_point($x,$y+0.25*("LayerFrom"+(("LayerTo"-"LayerFrom")/2))),2.4)`

where `$x` is calculated x-coordinate;
`$y+0.25("LayerFrom"+(("LayerTo"-"LayerFrom")/2)` is the y-coordinate with (pixel) offset based on depth
and `2.4` is the size of the created geometry.

For measurement '09', it gives the following result:

[image]

Now in QGIS 3.28.4 the points are set in the upper-left corner of the screen. I cannot figure out what changed and how to fix this. It seems like the coordinates are not calculated correctly/being ignored. Does anyone recognizes the problem?

Comment: What do you get with a simple make_point($x,$y) ?

Comment: That gives no result. ```make_circle((make_point($x,$y)),1)``` does give me points on the upper left corner. Furthermore I figured out that the problem is not in QGIS 3.24.0, but does occur in 3.26.0.

Comment: You can use x($geometry) instead of $x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use `x($geometry)` instead of `$x`